# How to print an access report protected by password?

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I have an password-protected Access database, and I need to print a report in this database from my VB.Net code. How can I do it? I have this so far:

```
Private Sub btnPrint_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnAfdrukken.Click

    Dim moApp As Access.Application
    Dim acViewPreview As Access.AcView

    Try
        moApp = DirectCast(GetObject(, "Access.Application"), Access.Application)
    Catch ex As Exception
        If TypeName(moApp) = "Nothing" Then
            moApp = DirectCast(CreateObject("Access.Application"), Access.Application)
        Else
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "VB/Office Guru™ Access Demo", _
            MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
        End If
    End Try

    moApp.Visible = True
    moApp.OpenCurrentDatabase("D:\media\urine (1).ACCDB")
    moApp.RunCommand(Access.AcCommand.acCmdAppMaximize)
    moApp.DoCmd.Maximize()
    moApp.DoCmd.SetWarnings(False)


    moApp.DoCmd.OpenReport("report1bw", acViewPreview)
    moApp.CloseCurrentDatabase()

End Sub
```

Comment: For normal data access you use ADO.Net, where the password is included as part of the connection string. For printing a report, I'm not sure.

Comment: What happens when you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the password when opening the file.

```
 moApp.OpenCurrentDatabase("D:\media\urine (1).ACCDB", bstrPassword := "somepassword")
```